# ruby blackjack game NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, null, nomethoderror

Here is the class definition that is generating the error:

```
class Hand
  attr_accessor :hand_cards, :hand_value

  def intitialize
    @hand_cards = []
    @hand_value = 0
  end

  def to_s
    "The hand is #{hand_cards} and has a value of #{hand_value}"
  end

  def add_card(new_card)
    hand_cards << new_card
  end

  def calculate_hand_value
    hand_cards.each do |card|
      case card[1]
        when '2'
        hand_value += 2
        when '3'
        hand_value += 3
        when '4'
        hand_value += 4
        when '5'
        hand_value += 5
        when '6'
        hand_value += 6
        when '7'
        hand_value += 7
        when '8'
        hand_value += 8
        when '9'
        hand_value += 9
        when '10'
        hand_value += 10
        when 'J'
        hand_value += 10
        when 'Q'
        hand_value += 10
        when 'K'
        hand_value += 10
        when 'A'
          if hand_value <= 10
            hand_value += 11
          else
            hand_value += 1
          end
      end   
    end
  end
end
```

When I create a Hand object and try to use the add_card method, I receive this error: OO-blackjack2.rb:43:in `add_card': undefined method`<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from OO-blackjack2.rb:108:in `'

I assume this means hand_cards has a value of nil, but per my initialize definition it should be set to an empty array and accessible via attr_accessor.  Please let me know if you need to see the entire program.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are spelling your constructor `intitialize` which means it won't be called by the `.new` method. It should be `initialize`.

Comment: That's the mistake I all the time did.. initially .. :p